# NUT slave powering off when master reboots

Tags: proxmox, ups, qnap, nut

I have a homelab with the following setup:

```
NAS (QNAP TS-453D)  <─usb─  UPS (CyberPower VP1000ELCD)
        |
     ethernet
        └>  Proxmox Server
```

The NAS is the UPS master, configured to poweroff after 5 minutes the AC fails.
[NAS ups configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8zMt.png)

The Proxmox server is a NUT slave with the following configuration:

```
cat /etc/nut/upsmon.conf | grep -v ^\# | grep  .
MONITOR qnapups@192.168.1.99 1 admin 123456 slave
MINSUPPLIES 1
SHUTDOWNCMD "/sbin/shutdown -h +0"
POLLFREQ 5
POLLFREQALERT 5
HOSTSYNC 15
DEADTIME 15
POWERDOWNFLAG /etc/killpower
RBWARNTIME 43200
NOCOMMWARNTIME 300
FINALDELAY 5
```

When the NAS reboots for updates the proxmox server poweroff, which is not what I want, I don't know how to differenciate a poweroff for updates from the one for AC fail.
Am I using the wrong setup/config?
Should I wire stuff in a different way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at https://networkupstools.org/docs/man/upsmon.conf.html

`DEADTIME seconds`

This parameter should be greater than the NAS restart time.